# Django id field coming None

Tags: django, django-models

This is the first time it has happened. Normally Django would automatically add a `primary key` field in the model but this time is giving a none value. I also added an `AutoField` to the model but its still giving `None`

This is my `Note` model:

```
class Note(models.Model):
    note_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    note = models.TextField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        l = self.title.lower().split(' ')
        self.slug = '_'.join(l)
        super(Note, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And this is the
[admin interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU3yQ.png)

Comment: does note_object.id return None??

Comment: have you run the `migrate` command after you added the field?

Comment: Yes I ran the migrate command after adding the field

Comment: Where and how are you printing it? Can you try using `.pk`?